# How can I update / insert data from a linked server query to SQL Server table using a trigger?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, linked-server

I am trying to update a SQL Server table from a linked server query automatically whenever a new record that matches the criteria is found. So I used triggers as follows, but it's not inserting/ updating records to the specified table. What did I miss here?

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[WORKORDERSCURDATE] 
ON [dbo].[WORKORDERS]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS 
    IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() > 1
        RETURN

    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO WORKORDERS    
            SELECT * 
            FROM OPENQUERY([DB29], 'SELECT DISTINCT Customers.CustomerID, Customers.Customer_Bill_Name, Customers.WhichShipVia, 
 LineItem.ItemID, JrnlHdr.INV_POSOOrderNumber, JrnlHdr.CustomerInvoiceNo, 
JrnlHdr.Comment2, JrnlHdr.ShipByDate, JrnlHdr.GoodThruDate, JrnlHdr.CustomerSONo, JrnlHdr.Reference, JrnlHdr.TransactionDate,
JrnlRow.DistNumber,  LineItem.SalesDescription, LineItem.PartNumber, LineItem.Category, LineItem.ItemClass, LineItem.ItemDescription 
                         FROM Customers
                         INNER JOIN JrnlHdr ON Customers.CustomerRecordNumber = JrnlHdr.CustVendId
                         LEFT OUTER JOIN Address ON Customers.CustomerRecordNumber = Address.CustomerRecordNumber
                         INNER JOIN JrnlRow ON JrnlHdr.PostOrder = JrnlRow.PostOrder
                         INNER JOIN LineItem ON JrnlRow.ItemRecordNumber = LineItem.ItemRecordNumber
                         WHERE JrnlHdr.JrnlKey_Journal = 11 
                           AND JrnlHdr.TransactionDate = CURDATE() 
                           AND JrnlHdr.PostOrder = JrnlRow.PostOrder  
                           AND JrnlHdr.CustVendId = Customers.CustomerRecordNumber 
                           AND JrnlRow.ItemRecordNumber = LineItem.ItemRecordNumber 
                           AND JrnlHdr.POSOisClosed = 0')
end
```

Comment: So you want to insert a second row into the WorkOrders table every single time a new row is inserted? And you are going to insert a new row into this table when a row is updated or deleted? You seem to have something horribly wrong in your design here.

Comment: @SeanLange even i remove ,UPDATE,DELETE still very slow and dont do what i am planing to do, yes i am trying to insert a second row into the WorkOrders table every single time a new row is inserted

Comment: That is a very strange way to handle data. But from your last comment I am more confused. In your original post you said it is not inserting but in your comment you said it is slow. Help us understand the issue here. Provide us with some information about what is going on. And give some serious consideration to how strange it is that you are going to insert a second row for every row insertion. Keep in mind that triggers in sql fire once per operation so if your insert statement inserts three rows this external data will happen once.

Comment: I have two issues here One is being the above statement very slow which takes around 20 minutes but that is not the main reason why i bring this question here the main reason for this question is updating WORK ORDER Table when new record is added to linked server  database.  linked server database is accounting software called sage we enter sales orders everyday so everyday whenever new sales order is added i would like to insert them into workorder table.   sorry for the confusion. i am a new to sql

Comment: Now I am even more confused. Your trigger doesn't update anything, it only does an insert. I think what you really are looking for here is a trigger on the remote sql server so that when something happens there it will update this data?

Answer (score 0):

What you describe in the comment above is the opposite of what you're doing.  Your trigger needs to be built on the remote server.  A trigger has to be built on a single object.  I assume the customers table is the one that would fire the trigger. The trigger would do an insert then on your local server.

Some advice, a trigger is probably not the best way to do this. What you're doing is essentially ETL (extract transform load).  This sort of thing is usually much more efficient to do in batch, even if it needs to be done frequently in small batches.

A stored procedure on your local server that periodically checks for new records on your remote server and then pulls them over would be a standard way to do this.

Comment: Thanks Chris that makes sense but i have no idea on how to create trigger on linked server. any help?

Comment: You have to log into the linked server directly to do it.